# comparing calendar objects with after or timeInMillis?

Tags: java, calendar

When comparing times i am converting the calendar object to TimeInMillis and then comparing which of them happened before while writing a comparator.

e.g Calendar event1 and event2 are two objects which decribe an event at some time in the past. I want to sort a list based on these events with the event which happened least recently be on the top. So i have the following code

```
private class LeastRecentEventComparator implements Comparator<Event>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Event o1, Event o2)
    {
        if (o1.getTimeInMillis() < o2.getTimeInMillis())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (o1.getTimeInMillis() > o2.getTimeInMillis())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want to understand if the better way of doing is using Calendar.after() or Calendar.before() methods.

Comment: Calendar is Comparable too, so you can also delegate to Calendar#compare instead.

Comment: thanks, i overlooked it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Calendar` compares using time in milliseconds as well, so both implementations are equivalent.

I personally recommend using the `compareTo(..)` method whenever the objects to be compared implement `Comparable` (`Calendar` does so), unless you want to explicitely deviate and specify your own sort order (in that case, I'd recommend creating your own Comparable implementation).